# Extract table rows from iframe with python, mechanize and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, iframe, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

I've been trying and looking for help like crazy, and I have not been able to solve this issue. Could you please help me on getting the table content inside the iFrame... On my code I was able to login in to the webpage and get in to the link were the "Web Page code" is, but never able to extract the rows.

Thanks!

Code:

Web page code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FKcPqbJO4NrhOShIUMmv_e3BDkPuyzRPMZOGInx8X4c/edit?usp=sharing)

iFrame code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UNr7Kgtt_rXjNav3YMxXtMKhsq7CD1X2cGpEbgoSFR8/edit?usp=sharing)